# github push issue in windows(uploading my repo to another github user(not private-public) that invited me)

Tags: git, github

I have my own account in github and I have a public repo that I successfully uploaded it to my github.
I want to push this repo that's in my gitHUB to another user that invited me to be one of its members in github(I accepted his/her invitation).
Im using windows 10, so how can I from my github push my repo that's found in my github to another user ? I mean how could I push my repo from my github to his/her github?

Could anyone please help me how can I do that in windows 10? thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can this help: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Comment: it's importing which means getting repo from other users, I need to export my repo to specific user in github ..

Comment: What are you currently using to manage git repositories? (e.g. git bash?)